# Finding Elasticity of Discount with Consumers

Tags: regression, elasticity

I was wondering what the best method to go about this would be. I have one year's worth of data and its related to air-travel. So I have ticket fares, passengers sent, discount applied on each ticket and some other variables such as GMV and revenue.

The data is for one airline and one flight only that is flying on a specific route, not multiple flights and multiple routes.

I want to estimate the elasticity between the discount rate ( the discount applied on each ticket ) and the number of passengers. That is, should the discount rate change by 1% how much would the number of passengers sent change by?

A regression in perhaps a log log form was the approach I was thinking but I want to avoid a spurious regression and ending up deriving incorrect assumptions.

Any ideas about changes to my approach? Should I perhaps use macro-economic variables too or should a different regression method be used altogether. Something what I was worried about was that elasticity is bound not to be constant. Because of travel has seasons, I'm assuming the elasticity is going to be highly inelastic when in peak travel season but elastic otherwise. So should I run the regression in batches of months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple observations of the same flight with your treatment variable (discount rate), along with other variables like time and whatever GMV stands for (is this gross merchandise value, i.e. what was sold on flight)?

This is a causal inference problem and regression is one way you can try to get the causal effect of interest as you describe. Really, you are looking for the causal effect of discount rate on the number of passengers sent. What I would start with before touching any model (or analyzing the data formally) is to first illustrate all of the important variables and relationships that cause changes in the number of passengers and/or changes in the discount rate. For example, you mention seasonality. This makes sense - I could believe that the discount rate given by the airline fluctuates depending on the season, and traveling naturally has seasonal patterns. This is a likely confounder and you should control for this (include month/quarter in the regression). Are there other variables that cause the airliner to change their discount rates? Are there other variables that cause variation in the number of passengers sent, irrespective of the discount rate? If yes, include these variables in the regression.

Does the current pandemic affect your data? Does your data have a natural trend in terms of the number of passengers (if so, then adding time might be useful to include).

Basically, I recommend creating a directed acyclic graph and illustrating, using domain knowledge and common sense, the causal relationships between your variables. Once you have this, then you can figure out what variables you should and should not include in your regression model to ensure an unbiased effect estimate. I don't think we can give much more advice than that because ultimately, you need to start with identifying the causal effect of interest fitst before moving to actually estimating it with statistics/ML.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response and recommendation. GMV does stand for gross merchandise value.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines as well and started identifying the relationships between the variables. Can you tell me why you suggest using a directed acyclic graph particularly?

Comment: @MSasta I suggest the directed acyclic graph because in my opinion, it is the easiest way to hypothesize what you know in a format that is clear. Using the directed acyclic graph, you can then proceed to identify the causal effect of interest, i.e. figure out the variables that you need to include in your regression model to obtain an unbiased coefficient by "blocking" on these variables, while also avoiding the mistake of including variables in your model that can actually lead to bias. There are many textbooks that talk about this, here's one:

Comment: https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/04-Graphical-Causal-Models.html, also basically any book by Judea Pearl and Statistical Rethinking by Richard McElreath

Comment: Basically, once you have the DAG, hopefully you can identify the causal effect of interest by blocking on the variables that lead to indirect associations between discount rate and number of passengers. Include these variables in your regression, and you should get the unbiased effect that you are looking for if your DAG is mostly correct.

Comment: Once again thank you for your detailed response @aranglol, ill look into the DAG, this puts me on a good track going forward!